# Spurious newlines+whitespace when printing substrings in C

Tags: c

I have a simple program that reads a pair of characters from a `char[]` array and prints each pair to the console, all on the same line - for some reason, some spurious newlines (and whitespace) are added to the output.

I've removed usage of str libs (apart from `strlen`) that may add newlines at the end of strings - but I am still lost as to what's happening.

The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char input[] = "aabbaabbaabbaabbaabb";

int main() {
    int i;
    char c[2];

    size_t input_length = strlen(input);

    for (i=0; i<input_length; i+=2) {
        c[0] = input[i];
        c[1] = input[i+1];
        
        printf("%s", c);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
aabbaabbabbaabbaabb
```

Output:

```
aabbaabbabb
aa
  bbaabb
```

Why are there newlines and whitespace in the output? (Note that the 1st line has a single `a` towards the end - could not deduce why)

Using Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16), though I would doubt if that matters.

Comment: You forgot to null-terminate `c`.  Change it to `char c[3];` and set `c[2] = '\0';`  Without that, the `%s` format will run past the end of `c` and start trying to print whatever it happens to encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` works properly if your string contains null character (`'\0'`). If it does not (just like your case), then `printf` function continues to print characters until it finds `'\0'` somewhere in memory. Remember that `string` in C is a character sequence terminated with `'\0'`. This is the reason why your code does not behave as you expected.

On the other hand, `%c` prints only one character so you can use:

```
printf("%c%c", c[0],c[1]);
```

If you persist in using `%s`, in this case you have to use `%.2s`. You probably already know that `.` shows precision in C. Precision in `string` means maximum number of characters that you want to print. So usage of `.2` results in printing the first two characters in your string. No need to wait for `'\0'`!

```
printf("%.2s", c);
```

I also give @Tom Karzes's solution. You should change and add these lines:

```
char c[3];
c[2] = '\0';
```