# Confusion regarding output of a program related to Null character

Tags: arrays, c, string, null, character

In the below program arr is a char array whose length is 4. On running it in C compiler I found that the output is tjyh.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char arr[4];
    arr[0]='t';
    arr[1]='j';
    arr[2]='y';
    arr[3]='h';
    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I am confused as where is the Null character. Since a string ends with a '\0' there should be space to accommodate it. How does "%s" know when to stop. Since there is no '\0', there should be garbage values after tjyh or the output should just be tjy since the last character is '\0' which replaced 'h'.

Edit: Well, I ran this code in [Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/ide) compiler and got the output to be tjyh and no garbage values and if you think that it should also print garbage values then please tell me for how long should it print garbage values as I did not entered '\0', so when would the program stop printing?

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: This should print 'tjyh+garbage' not only 'tjyh' depending on what exist on the memory next.

Comment: The last element of your char array has to be `\0` so add this character. That is, make these changes: `char arr[5];` and `arr[4]='\0'; `. You can also look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624051/spurious-newlineswhitespace-when-printing-substrings-in-c)

Comment: The array does not end with `0`. It has four elements, none of which is `0`.

Comment: If it did not print garbage values, then it just happened to find a `0` byte after the array. if it did not it would output garbage until it found one.

Answer (score 1):

> Since there is no '\0', there should be garbage values after tjyh…

How do you know there is no `'\0'` there? You put letters in `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`, and `arr[3]`. What did you put after that? Nothing. So how do you know what is there?

In fact, you defined an array of only four bytes, `char arr[4];`, so the compiler arranged that much space for you. You do not know what is in memory beyond that array. You do not know whether there is a null character there or not.

So, maybe there is a null character there, and, when you execute `printf("%s",arr);`, it prints the four characters you assigned, sees the null character, and stops.

In other circumstances, maybe in a more complicated program, there might be other data after the array `arr`, and `printf` would not see a null character just after `arr` and would not stop.

The above is what happens in a simple C implementation. However, compilers are getting more sophisticated, and a compiler might recognize that the call to `printf` with an unterminated string results in behavior that is not defined by the C standard. During optimization, code that has undefined behavior may be transformed in unexpected ways, so your program might not print “tjyh” at all; it might trap or execute completely different code.